# How to check if a string contains one of the elements from an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string `var str = "I like roses";` and an array containing `var arr1 = ['roses','daisy','lily','petunia']`

I want to check if my string contains one or more than one element of the array `arr1`.

Expected Output : `str contains an element from arr1`
How can I do that in javascript?

I know how to check all the elements in an array using `.every`.

```
var str = 'I will have a mango and a banana';
var arr = ['mango','banana'];

var isEvery = arr.every(item => str.includes(item));

console.log(isEvery);
```

Output: `true`

How can I do it for just one element?

Comment: `Array.prototype.some`

Comment: `let hasSome = arr.some(item => str.includes(item));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) has already been proposed by @Ele and will likely best suit your needs.

One can take the funky route and use a regex

```js
const v = ['mango', 'banana'] 
const check = s => !!s.match(new RegExp(`(${v.join('|')})`))
console.log(check('me mango and banana'))//true
console.log(check('me mango'))//true
console.log(check('me nothing'))//false
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution but this should work. Im sure you can clean it up

```
const arrayCompare = () =>{
    const str = "I like roses";

    const arr1 = ['roses','daisy','lily','petunia']

    const newArray = str.split(' ');
    for(let element of newArray){

        if(arr1.includes(element)){
            return 'String contains element from arr1'
        }

    }
    return false;


};
```